# Google Sheets - last row in every tab

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with 4 tabs. I'd like it to load to the last row on each tab every time the document is opened. I have a script that runs now that opens the active tab to the last row, but if we change tabs we have to refresh the Google Sheet to get the script to run again. This works, but I'd like for it to be automatic instead of my users having to refresh (and refreshing is faster than scrolling down btw).

Current scprit:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name:"MyFunction", functionName:"myFunction"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
   myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var lastrow = mysheet.getLastRow();

  mysheet.setActiveCell(mysheet.getDataRange().offset(lastrow-1, 0, 1, 1));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inquiring about this earlier this year and to all my months of research, it appears that this may not yet be a function available to script. I did speak to a friend of mine that works at google apps department and it seems this is not yet available.

I know this information was from 2016, however it is helpful to understand
how google sheets works `onOpen`. Hope this helps.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99994/jump-to-the-end-of-data-in-all-sheets-not-just-the-current-one

Comment: Thank you for the link, I appreciate knowing that. I don't understand while it's not  a function, it seems much more logical to open to the last row instead of the first on a sheet. Or at least give me the option. It should be built in, in my opinion. My research shows that others have this issue as well. Thanks for the help. I will keep searching and post back here if a true solution is found, instead of a keyboard workaround.